# Taking Control of ARCamera on Unity3D with Vuforia

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, vuforia

The `position` and `rotation` of Vuforia's `ARcam` are determined by their algorithms to give the `AR` effect. I'd like to know how to do the following:

1. When some object is clicked the camera goes to some specific position (for that I need to somehow take control of the camera).
2. Also have to possibility to yield control of the camera back to Vuforia.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a second camera in this instance. Position the second camera at the AR Camera position, then adjust the depths to make the new camera the view that you see. Then you can tween its position to the predefined one you have.

Do the reverse to get control back to the AR Camera.

Comment: My current implementation takes that approach. But there is a small pause between during the switch.